# Non standard evaluation of dplyr summarise_ leads to different results

Tags: r, dplyr

I want call `summarise_` of `dplyr` package in my function, here is what I tried but I get different for `mean` and `median` function, what's wrong with my approach?

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3))
getMean <- function(df, col) {
  col <- as.symbol(col)
  df %>%
    summarise_(Mean = ~mean(col))
}

getMedian <- function(df, col) {
  col <- as.symbol(col)
  df %>%
    summarise_(Median = ~median(col))
}

getMean(df, 'A')
   Mean
1    2

getMedian(df, 'A')
Error: object 'A' not found
```

Comment: The reason `median` is treated differently than `mean` is that `mean` (as well as `sum`, `min`, `max`, `var`, and `sd`) are treated as special cases by the `summarise` operation, which calls a C++ shortcut for each of them. You can find that list of functions [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/50309db8f04cbcc87e4568a4bfa1f0c718e824c9/inst/include/dplyr/Result/factories.h).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `lazyeval`

```
library(lazyeval)
library(dplyr)
getMedian <- function(df, col) {
          df %>%
           summarise_(.dots= list(Median=interp(~median(v), v= as.name(col))))
    }

getMedian(df, 'A')
#  Median
#1      2
```

We could use a single function to do the `mean`, `median` etc. by using the function name as argument.

```
getFun <- function(df, col, func) {
      FUN <- match.fun(func)
      nm1 <- sub('^(.)', '\\U\\1', substitute(func), perl=TRUE)
      df %>%
        summarise_(interp(~FUN(v), v= as.name(col)))%>%
        setNames(., nm1)
}

getFun(df, 'A', median)
#  Median
#1      2
getFun(df, 'A', mean)
#  Mean
#1    2

getFun(df, 'A', var)
#  Var
#1   1

getFun(df, 'A', min)
#  Min
#1   1
getFun(df, 'A', max)
#  Max
#1   3
```